# Fragment coming below the container screen

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to add a fragment above an activity. I am adding the fragment on the main container, but instead of ovrlapping the Activity screen, the fragment is coming below the layout of the mainActivity. I know its a very silly question to ask but was unable to find a solution. Below I am posting my code. Need your suggestions.

```
MainActivity.java:

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
EditText email, password;
    TextView login,signup;

    public FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    public FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    Fragment fragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailVal);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordVal);
        login = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login);
        signup = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.signUP);
        fragment = new SignupFragment();
        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.maine, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("backfrag");
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });





activity_main.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/maine"
    tools:context="com.hubbellindia.lightdemo1.MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="LOGIN" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:hint=" Enter Email"
        android:id="@+id/emailVal"
        android:background="@drawable/edit"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"

        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:hint=" Enter Password"
        android:id="@+id/passwordVal"
        android:background="@drawable/edit"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"

        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="LOGIN"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#ee4356"
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Sign up"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/signUP"
       android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

SignUpFragment.java:

    public class SignupFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signup, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event


}

fragment_signup.xml:

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.hubbellindia.lightdemo1.SignupFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.hubbellindia.lightdemo1.MainActivity">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="SIGNUP" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:hint=" Enter Email"
            android:id="@+id/emailValNew"
            android:background="@drawable/edit"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"

            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:hint=" Enter Password"
            android:id="@+id/passwordValNew"
            android:background="@drawable/edit"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"

            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="SIGNUP"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#ee4356"
            android:id="@+id/signup"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>


    </LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: can you please add screen shots..

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace you `activity` layout to this

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.hubbellindia.lightdemo1.MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="LOGIN"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailVal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit"
        android:hint=" Enter Email"

        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordVal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit"
        android:hint=" Enter Password"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="#ee4356"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="LOGIN"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/signUP"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Sign up"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/maine"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And replace your fragment into `FramLayout` - `maine` to avoid overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

```
try it
        **1)activity_main.xml`enter code here`**

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/activity_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context="com.example.admin.androidmodule.MainActivity">

            <Button
                android:text="Button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:elevation="0dp" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            </FrameLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    **2)MainActivity** 

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                    DemoFragment demoFragment = new DemoFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,demoFragment, "demoFragment").commit();

                }
            });
        }
    }
```